# Exporting SSL Cert private keys in IIS 7.0

Tags: iis, iis-7, ssl, ssl-certificate

In IIS 6 on Server 2003, I can go to a web site's properties and walk through the wizard to generate a new cert request. Once I complete the request and have the cert installed on the web site, I can go into the cert store and export the certificate with the private key, setting a password and saving it as a PFX file.

When I go through a similar procedure in IIS 7 on 2008R2, I can generate the CSR and complete the request. However, the cert in the cert store cannot be exported with the private key and saved as a PFX file. Is there some option or step I am missing in the process so that the private key can be exported in IIS 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIS still has the option to export the certificates directly; alternatively, you can export the certificate using the "Certificates" MMC snap-in (`certmgr.msc`).

[image: certificate]

If this isn't available, you may have set the private key as non-exportable during the key creation process.

Comment: Right, the issue is that I cannot figure out how to set the key as exportable during the creation process. I never saw an option one way or the other. Is this configured in a cert template somewhere?

Comment: @Andy The IIS wizard doesn't include that option - it tries to keep it simple; certificates are exportable by default.  It could be in the template - check the template that was used during creation.  First things first, though - you've verified that the key is indeed set to non-exportable?

Comment: When i open the cert in cert manager, i do not see the key icon and a message saying "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate." Are there any other verification steps I can take?  How would I go about checking the template? We are using Entrust as the CA.

Comment: @Andy Sounds like the private key may not have gotten imported somehow.

Comment: It worked fine on a different server. There must have been something wacky with the first one I tried it on.

Answer (score 5):

In case this is of any help, I had better luck with a variation to Shane's answer.

1. Visit the Server Certificates tab in IIS.
2. Right-click the certificate and choose **View** (instead of Export).
3. This opens the certificate in a new window. Click the Details tab.
4. Click **Copy to File...**. This opens a different export wizard that has a few more options to choose from.

Comment: This is good confirmation that I don't have a private key : it says 'The associated private key cannot be found'. I assume I need to re-key the cert